# What are the odds of this?

Tags: cash-game

Played poker two nights ago and the result ended up being quad kings over quad queens over aces full of kings. it was insane

Answer (score 1):

There is only one way for the hand to run this way.

Player A: AA
Player B: KK
Player C: QQ

Board: AKKQQ

Fairly we can assume no one folds when dealt these hands.

% AA (1/221), 4% of the time at least one player has AA in a 9-handed game.
% KK (1/204.17) assuming someone has AA, 3.85% of the time for the remaining 8 players
% QQ (1/188), assuming 2 players have AA/KK, 3.66% of the time for the remaining 7 players

Chance of AA+KK+QQ in a 9 handed game = ~0.0056453%. This is a slight overestimation because it doesnt account for 2 players having AA (or KK/QQ).

Chance of board running AAKKQ or AKKQQ or AAKQQ (6 outs) = 6!/(46!/41!)

Chance of board running AKKQQ = [6!/(46!/41!)]/3 = ~0.00014590%

Chance of your scenario in 9 handed game = 8.23*10^-11, or 1 every 12140663652 times.

If there were 1,000 9-handed poker tables running at average rate of 30 hands/hour, it would take about 50 years for one hand to be that scenario you described. Not all that impossible, although its more likely someone is rigging your deck.